# Smooth bijection has a dense open subset in which the inverse is also smooth

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be smooth and bijective. Prove there exists open subset $U$ and $V$ dense in  $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f: U \longrightarrow V$ has a smooth inverse.

I would like to do this using the rank theorem. I would think that the set of points at which the differential is not invertible are isolated or something like that, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it (if it's even true).

This i my main problem; if I suppose  $\text{rank} df(x)=k<n$ then the rank cannot be equal to $k$ in a neighborhood of x, otherwise the rank theorem applies and it gives me that $f$ is not surjective. Therefore i get a sequence of points converging to $x$ with rank different than $k$, but how does this help me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Sard's theorem, which says that the set of critical values has measure zero, might be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard's_theorem

Comment: OK, thank you, but can we prove it using rank theorem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rank theorem. Could you state it?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, if the rank of the differential is constantly equal to $k$ around a point $x_0$, then up to diffeomorpshism the function has the following form around  $x_0$ : $f(y_1,..., y_n)=(y_1,...,y_k,0,..0)$ (or $f(y_1,..., y_n)=(y_1,...,y_k)$ depending on which dimension is bigger)

Comment: Actually I'm just looking for a proof that uses basic tools of analysis, like rank /implicit/inverse function theorem, and no measure theory

Comment: You have said that in a neighborhood $U$ of any point $x$, there must exist a point $x_0$ at which the rank is $n$ (of course, the inverse function theorem gives an open neighborhood of $x_0$ in which $f$ is smoothly invertible). Isn't this precisely the definition of denseness?

Comment: To elaborate, it seems that $U$ can be defined as a union of the open neighborhoods around $x_0$ guaranteed by the inverse function theorem, where the union is taken over all points $x_0$ where the rank is $n$. Since there exists such an $x_0$ in any open set, $U$ must be dense. (The denseness of $V = f(U)$ is another issue.)

Comment: Perhaps I'm being a little careless here. You said that in any open set and for each $k < n$, there's a point where the rank is not $k$. I suppose it's not immediately clear that there's in fact a point where the rank is $n$.

Comment: I'll try this way: we know that the rank can only increase in a small neighborhood of a point. So there exists a point where the rank is at least 1, otherwose the function would be constant. But in a neighbourhood of that point the rank has to be greater or equal to 1. It can't be constantly 1, so there existst a point in which the rank is 2, and so on, untill I get the existence of a point where I have maximal rank